# Ajax pegando só o primeiro id

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá, estou fazendo um update de uma lista com arrays e php, passando dois parametros presença(ckeckbox) que retorna true ou false e o id no hidden, mas o id não prosegue no loop ficando no primeiro id nos dois valores:

> ```
> array(2) {
>   ["id"]=>
>   array(2) {
>     [0]=>
>     string(1) "2"
>     [1]=>
>     string(1) "2"
>   }
>   ["presenca"]=>
>   array(2) {
>     [0]=>
>     string(5) "false"
>     [1]=>
>     string(4) "true"
>   }
> ```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn_update').click(function(){  
   
     var id = [];
     var presenca = [];
  
     $(':checkbox').each(function(i){
     
      presenca[i] = $('#permissao').val(); 
      id[i] = $('#id').val();
       if(presenca[i] == this.checked){
        this.checked = true;
        presenca[i] = this.checked;
        
       }else{
        this.checked = false;
        presenca[i] =this.checked;
        
       }
     });
     
    
      $.ajax({
       url:'<?php echo WEBROOT; ?>/sistema/modulos/processa-permissao.php',
       method:'POST',
       data:{id:id, presenca:presenca},
       success:function()
       {
        alert('update ok'); 
       }
       
      });
     
   });
```

A intenção fica sendo caso o usuário marque ou não o ajax insere o update em looping.

Em que estou errando?

Comment: tenta passas as variaveis assim 'id[]:id', 'presenca[]:presenca' . e posta o erro do console

Comment: da linha do data não prosseguiu a leitura, data:{id:id, presenca:presenca},

Answer (score 1):

[Resolvido] Coloquei um atributo no check box e utilizei o attr();
Só fica a dúvida, type='hidden' causa efeito único no dom?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn_update').click(function(){  
   
     var id = [];
     var presenca = [];
  
     $(':checkbox').each(function(i){
     
      presenca[i] = $('#permissao').val(); 
      //id[i] = $('#id').val(); Aqui está o erro
                      id[i] = $(this).attr("idpega");
       if(presenca[i] == this.checked){
        this.checked = true;
        presenca[i] = this.checked;
        
       }else{
        this.checked = false;
        presenca[i] =this.checked;
        
       }
     });
     
    
      $.ajax({
       url:'<?php echo WEBROOT; ?>/sistema/modulos/processa-permissao.php',
       method:'POST',
       data:{id:id, presenca:presenca},
       success:function()
       {
        alert('update ok'); 
       }
       
      });
     
   });
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  id="permissao" '.$permission.' value="'.$relaciona.'" idpega="'.$user_id.'" >
<!-- Criei um atributo para o mesmo checkbox colocando o id -->
```